# What is the idiomatic way to build functions over newtypes ("wrapped types") in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Let `StringWrapper1` and `StringWrapper2` be two types that wrap over a string (i.e. `newtype StringWrapper1 = StringWrapper1 String` and `newtype StringWrapper2 = StringWrapper2`).

Now suppose we're trying to craft a function from `StringWrapper1` to `StringWrapper2`.

```
funcWrapper :: StringWrapper1 -> StringWrapper2
```

On the one hand, we want to be explicit that what we're passing into this function is a `StringWrapper1`, so we don't want merely treat `StringWrapper1` as a type synonym for `String` (that leads to bugs, as my own experience can attest). On the other hand, when conceptually building the function, we are still somehow thinking in terms of `String`s. What we want to do then is to first build `func` which doesn't us to constantly wrap and unwrap types:

```
func :: String -> String
```

Then, we use `func` to build `funcWrapper`:

```
funcWrapper :: StringWrapper1 -> StringWrapper2
funcWrapper (StringWrapper1 str) = StringWrapper2 (func str)
```

**Problem/Question:** Is this idiomatic? It seems awkward to constantly be duplicating every function with a `func` and a `funcWrapper`. Does Haskell provide some other way of doing this that I'm missing? Or should I just use type synonyms?

Comment: If you are _conceptually thinking of strings_, then why do you need the type-level distinction? The point of a different type is that you think about something conceptually different, even if the actual implementation is a string.

Comment: I think `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` is often a better answer than using something like `coerce` (which the answers here seem to focus on), but it depends on the situation.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, you should make sure this is really what you want to do (see leftaroundabout's comment). If it is, you can use [`coerce` from the standard library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html) to convert between types that have the same runtime representation:

```
func :: String -> String
func = ...

...

funcWrapper :: StringWrapper1 -> StringWrapper2
funcWrapper = coerce func
```

Comment: This seems to be the most elegant. Is its use frowned upon?

Comment: @George No, I have never seen it frowned upon if this is actually what you want to do (usually you want a newtype to be "opaque" outside at some point though. Usually outside of the module its defined in). `coerce` also has zero overhead (which is not the case for the wrapping/unwrapping solution) because it is eliminated during compilation. Note that `coerce` is very different from `unsafeCoerce`. `coerce` is always safe.

Comment: The wrapping and unwrapping solution also has zero overhead.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Ahh, that's right. The overhead difference would come into play if you had something like `map (\(StringWrapper1 str) -> str) wrappers` vs `coerce wrappers :: [String]`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should take into account leftaroundabout's comment and make sure the newytpes are actually meaningful. That said, this sort of wrapping and unwrapping is everyday stuff indeed, but you can make it more convenient. One way is taking advantage of how your string wrappers are monomorphic functors (as opposed to `Functor`s, which are polymorphic), and so you can write mapping functions such as:

```
mapWrapper1 :: (String -> String) -> StringWrapper1 -> StringWrapper1
mapWrapper1 f (StringWrapper1 str) = StringWrapper1 (f str)

mapWrapper2 :: (String -> String) -> StringWrapper2 -> StringWrapper2
mapWrapper2 f (StringWrapper2 str) = StringWrapper2 (f str)
```

A well-known generalisation of this pattern is the [`MonoFunctor`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.6/mono-traversable-1.0.1/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFunctor) class from the *mono-traversable* package.

It is also easy to define a conversion function between the two wrappers (in fancy jargon, we would say it is a natural transformation between the two functors):

```
rewrap1as2 :: StringWrapper1 -> StringWrapper2
rewrap1as2 (StringWrapper1 str) = StringWrapper2 str
```

(`rewrap1as2` can be implemented simply as `coerce` from `Data.Coerce`. See [David Young's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40346504/2751851) for details.)

The `wrap` from [user2297560's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40346082/2751851) can then be defined in terms of these more elementary functions:

```
mapAndRewrap1as2 :: (String -> String) -> StringWrapper1 -> StringWrapper2
mapAndRewrap1as2 f = rewrap1as2 . mapWrapper1 f
```

If you want something even less verbose, you might appreciate the [*newtype*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype-0.2) package, or the [equivalent `Iso`s provided by *lens*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Wrapped.html). That, however, is probably worth a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just write a function that will wrap any other function?

```
wrap :: (String -> String) -> StringWrapper1 -> StringWrapper2
wrap f (StringWrapper1 str) = StringWrapper2 (f str)
```

This will lift any `String -> String` into a `StringWrapper1 -> StringWrapper2`.

Comment: This is elegant; however, you'll still be having to create these wrapper functions for each function type.  And what if `StringWrapper1` is embedded into a record data structure? There still seems to be a lot of duplication.

Comment: But at the end of the day: is the solution in your post the idiomatic  Haskell approach?

Comment: @George Note however that "to create these wrapper functions" amounts to using `wrap f` where I would have used `f`. There is no need to provide a definition for all such functions with its own identifier. I'd just define the plain `f` and make the caller use `wrap f` whenever needed. No duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [*newtype-generics*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype-generics-0.5) package, one can write something like

```
{-# language DeriveGeneric #-}
module Main where

import GHC.Generics
import Control.Newtype (Newtype,over)

newtype StringWrapper1 = StringWrapper1 String deriving Generic

instance Newtype StringWrapper1

newtype StringWrapper2 = StringWrapper2 String deriving Generic

instance Newtype StringWrapper2

func :: String -> String
func = undefined

funcWrapper :: StringWrapper1 -> StringWrapper2
funcWrapper = over StringWrapper1 func
```

I would not define the wrapper function and instead use [`over`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype-generics-0.5/docs/Control-Newtype.html#v:over) at each site.