# How to multiply custom datatype objects inline?

Tags: haskell

To create the datatype-based heterogeneous list described [in this Haskell Wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Heterogenous_collections), one can define  a datatype `T` as:

```
data T = ConsInt    Int
       | ConsString String
       | ConsChar   Char
```

And then create an object using:

```
ConsInt 200
```

How does one then multiply an object `T`? If we use the type constructor `Maybe` as in:

```
Just 200
```

We can use `fmap (*2) (Just 200)` to multiply it by 2 and output a `Just 400`.

Doing `fmap (*2) (ConsInt 200)` doesn't work, however. (I'm guessing because `T` is not a *type constructor* but a *data type*)

How, then, does one multiply a `T` object inline, without having to define a function by hand:

```
mult2 :: T -> T
mult2 (ConsInt r) = ConsInt ((*2) r)
```

Or how does one use a simpler anonymous function than this:

```
(\(ConsInt r) -> ConsInt ((*2) r)) (ConsInt 200)
```

[Runnable example](http://rextester.com/VOMWE95595)

Comment: What should hapoen if your value is `ConsString String`? It's of the same type `T`. How do you propose to multiply it?

Comment: Terminology nitpicking: "how does one then multiply an object `T`?" -- just call it "a value `T`": it is simpler and, arguably, more accurate.

Comment: I don’t think this is what you want for this case, but a good package to be aware of is [mono-traversable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable), which provides classes for “containers” of a fixed element type (e.g. `Text` is a container of `Char`). For example, you only ever wanted to map over the `ConsInt` constructor, you would add `type instance Element T = Int` and make an instance of [`MonoFunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.8.1/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFunctor) with `omap f (ConsInt x) = ConsInt (f x); omap _ x = x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Doing `fmap (*2) (ConsInt 200)` doesn't work, however. (I'm guessing because `T` is not a *type constructor* but a *data type*)

This is part of the reason. `fmap (*2) (Just 200)` works because `Maybe` is a type constructor which is an instance of `Functor`:

```
GHCi> :t fmap
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
GHCi> :set -XTypeApplications
GHCi> :t fmap @Maybe
fmap @Maybe :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
```

`Functor`s have to be type constructors, which take a type and produce another type (that is, they have to have kind `* -> *`):

```
GHCi> :k Functor
Functor :: (* -> *) -> Constraint
```

That is so because, to put it roughly, `fmap` should be able to change the type argument to the type constructor to anything else -- note how `a` and `b` in `fmap`'s type signature are completely arbitrary. If you have...

```
data T
    = ConsInt Int
    | ConsString String
    | ConsChar Char
```

... then a `T` value cannot possibly contain anything other than an `Int`, a `String` or a `Char`, and so that requirement for it to be a `Functor` cannot be satisfied. If you really wanted to insist on making it a `Functor`, one course of action would be poking a hole where `Int` is:

```
-- You can actually write a Functor instance for this:
data T a
    = ConsStuff a
    | ConsString String
    | ConsChar Char
```

Though that can be an useful refactoring in other circumstances, I'm pretty sure you won't want to do that here.

> How, then, does one multiply a `T` object inline, without having to define a function by hand [...] or how does one use a simpler anonymous function than [...]

Note that if you were to give `T` a `Functor` instance, the implementation of `fmap` would be about as complicated as the function you are pondering about here. (I'm disregarding the fact that, thanks to the `DeriveFunctor` extension, you never actually have to write a `Functor` instance, but that's kind of besides the point.) For the sake of comparison, this is what [the `Functor` instance for `Maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-812) looks like:

```
instance  Functor Maybe  where
    fmap _ Nothing       = Nothing
    fmap f (Just a)      = Just (f a)
```

If you want something more general than `mult2 :: T -> T`, you can define `mapConsInt :: (Int -> Int) -> T -> T` instead. By the way, note that your definitions of `mult2` don't handle the `ConsString` and `ConsChar` cases, and neglecting that is almost always a bad idea. The obvious way of fixing that would be by adding do-nothing cases for the other constructors (just like is done in `fmap` for `Maybe`); depending on what you want to do, though, you might prefer making your function return a `Maybe T` instead of a `T` (in that case, note that a name started with "map" wouldn't be as appropriate as before).

P.S.: A properly implemented `mapConsInt :: (Int -> Int) -> T -> T` is very much like an `fmap`, except that it is restricted to a specific function type. In fact, it isn't actually wrong to say that we are dealing with a functor here, as long as we have it clear that it is a functor that isn't a `Functor`. (It isn't a `Functor` for the reasons discussed above, i.e. because it  can only map `Int -> Int` functions.) For some considerations about how to handle such situations (as well as pointers to things you might want to know about at some point), see [*What is the idiomatic way to build functions over newtypes ("wrapped types") in Haskell?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40345838/2751851) and [*Haskell: Functor instance for newtype*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49050558/2751851) (the fact that both questions happen to mention newtypes isn't essential).

Comment: I had some of my terminology mixed up. Thanks for clarifying that a type constructor is an instance of `Functor`. I will look further into Functor instances. Also, perhaps I was expecting `mapConsInt` to be a built-in map function for all new data types (like a field lookup function when using record syntax). Using `mapConsInt (*2) (ConsInt 200)` does look much nicer than a lambda function though, even with the extra definition.

Comment: @vasilyrud: If you’re going to be implementing many of these convenience functions like `mapConsInt`, they can all be expressed with a generic “fold” function: `foldT :: (Int -> r) -> (String -> r) -> (Char -> r) -> T -> r; foldT i s c t = case t of { ConsInt x -> i x; ConsString x -> s x; ConsChar x -> c x }`. This is akin to `maybe :: r -> (a -> r) -> Maybe a -> r` or `either :: (a -> r) -> (b -> r) -> Either a b -> r`. With this, you can easily derive other functions like `mapT i s c = foldT (ConsInt . i) (ConsString . s) (ConsChar . c)` and `mapConsInt f = mapT f id id`.